# Google OAuth DataStore - How to find the scope(s) of a stored credential

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-oauth

I'm building an integration with Google API's on a Java platform. I need to access both the Calendar as send mails on behalf of users. The application is a Web server application. I'm using the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)

I've followed and read the documentation on [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). I followed the Authorization code flow documentation and am able to obtain a code and change that for an access and refresh token. Accessing the APIs with the access token also works. I'm persisting the refresh token using an implementation of a [DataStoreFactory](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/store/DataStoreFactory), [DataStore](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/store/DataStore) and [StoredCredential](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/StoredCredential). This implementation stores the credentials in a database. I've also read about [Incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth)

> To implement incremental authorization, you complete the normal flow for requesting an access token **but make sure that the authorization request includes previously granted scopes**. This approach allows your app to avoid having to manage multiple access tokens.

In short my question would be: Can i derive the previously granted scopes based on the stored tokens?

As far as I understand the data store only has knowledge about the owner of the credential. In my case identified by the ID of the user. And the contents of the credential. *I would expect that somewhere the SDK has stored which scopes are attached to the token. So when i need to get authorization for a scope, i can check if we have a token that gives access to that scope.* If we don't, we can try to get one. If we already have a token for that user we need to know which scope they give access to, so we can use the incremental authorization to get a new combined token that authorizes the collections of scopes.

Another option would be to store the tokens for every scope separately, but than again the question remains how to identify the scope in the datastore, since I can only provide an id and a value.